# Ascending order substring compile error

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, compiler-errors, substring

I am trying to create a program that reads the longest ascending substring from any given numerical inputs.

(Eg. input = "43123" output = "123")

I have finished editing the loops but the program doesn't compile and keeps mentioning the "missing return statement" for the second last closing bracket.

I have tried adding return asc; and break; but neither seems to work.

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;        
public class Ascending{


    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.print("Enter a number = ");

        //scan the input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = in.nextLine();

        //print solution
        System.out.println("output = " + itsAscending(n));


    }

    public static String itsAscending(String n) {

        int length = n.length();    

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            char first = n.charAt(i);       
                char next = n.charAt(i+1);      
            int f = (int)(first - 48);       
            int nx = (int)(next - 48);      

            String asc;
            String works = ""; 

            if (f<nx) {

                works = works + n.substring(i, i+2);
                asc = works.substring(0, works.length()-1); 
                return asc;
            }

            else {

                works = works + "";
                asc = works.substring(i, works.length()-1); 
                return asc;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You mention a "compile error" but don't show it. Please show the text of your error and indicate by comment which line of code causes it. Also, please fix your code's formatting by making your indentation consistent. Proper code formatting will often help you (and us) debug your program. Improper formatting makes your code almost impossible to read and interpret.

Comment: Perhaps it complains there's no return _after_ the `for` loop (and it can't prove one of those inside will be encountered).

Comment: Good catch. If length is 0 the loop is not run at all, so and end return is needed.

Comment: You need a return outside the for loop. So instead of returning asc inside the else statement, return it outside the loop.

Comment: @Ali AlamiriYou are right actually. Now that I added that and defined the variable outside the for-loop it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Alamiri is right, in case n's length is 0 you will never enter into the for loop so you will not have a return value. @Ali Alamiri should receive the credits for the answer

Comment: Now I wish I put the comment as an answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my comment as an answer, in case someone faces a similar problem.

You need a return outside the for loop. So instead of returning asc inside the else statement, return it outside the loop